# Read Identity options from inside controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

With ASP.NET Core identities I can set whether or not I want to allow logins without a confirmed email address like so:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(config =>
    {
        config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail = true;
    })
```

This has knock on effects for the logic of my site but I want to be able to switch back and forth between these modes while I am developing.

Is there anyway I can read this value inside a controller?

Like:

```
if(config.SignIn.RequireConfirmedEmail == true) 
     DoSomething();
```

Comment: Try `HttpContext.Identity`. Will be filled when the user has been authenticated.

Comment: I'm trying to add conditional to signup logic so need to read the global setting as I need to do different pre-signup checks